# Changing the text size in the console

Tags: c, colors, printf

I changed the font color and made it bold. How do I change its size?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COLOR_BOLD "\e[1m"
#define COLOR_OFF "\e[m"
#define CYAN "\033[36m"

int main(void)
{
    printf(COLOR_BOLD CYAN "Hello\n" COLOR_OFF);
}
```

Comment: You can change font size in terminal emulator setting.

Comment: This needs to be done for a specific text, not for everything

Comment: Is my assumption correct that with "console" you are referring to a console on Microsoft Windows?

Comment: A console is quite basic: all the text is likely to be the same monospace font, in the same size.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I doubt that this is possible to do in a Microsoft Windows console. I believe the text size must be the same for all text. I'm afraid that you will have to create a graphical application using [GDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface), GDI+ or [Direct2D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct2D) if you want text with different font sizes.

Answer (score 1):

C has no concept of font size. It will just output characters. it has nothing to do with ISO C.

As in your example code, only bold and color handling is possible.

Comment: MS has a set of console control functions. The one [controlling the font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setcurrentconsolefontex) has been deprecated, in favour of [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) but I don't think these have a font control, but accessed through the console window properties.